# Can we conclude if a Series is Conditionally Convergent, it is not Absolutely Convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

I got this doubt when i framed my own series given as:
$$P=\sum \frac{1}{3^{-n}+n}$$

To test the Convergence of the above series i started analyzing its alternate series :

$$S=\sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{-n}+n}$$

We have in $S$ $$a_n=\frac{1}{3^{-n}+n}$$ satisfies:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$$

Also taking:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{3^{-x}+x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{\ln 3-3^x}{(3^x)(3^{-x}+x)^2} \lt 0$$

So the Sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is Monotone Decreasing

Hence Leibnitz test conditions satisfied

So
$$S=\sum (-1)^{n-1}a_n=\sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{3^{-n}+n}$$
is Conditionally Convergent

From this can we conclude that the Series:

$$\sum \left|a_n \right|$$ is Divergent that is the Original Series $P$ is Divergent?

Comment: No, $\sum \frac1{n^2+3^{-n}}$ and $\sum \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2+3^{-n}}$ both converge, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Alternating series test doesn't tell you if the series is conditionally convergence, it just tells you if the series is convergence. It's more often used for conditionally convergence series, because if the series is absolutely convergence there are many other test you can use.

As an example, $\sum (-\frac{1}{2})^{k}$ is a convergence series by alternating series test, but it's also absolutely convergence.

Conditionally convergence, by definition, require that it's not absolutely convergence. But checking for conditionally convergence generally mean checking that it's convergence and also checking that it's not absolutely convergence. I don't know any examples where you can check for conditional convergence directly, without checking that it's not absolutely convergence first.

In your example, it's very to check that the original series is divergence by a limit comparison test to the harmonic series.

Comment: That should be "convergent" (adjective), not "convergence" (noun).